# Show users horizontal scroll is available on mobile

Tags: android, mobile, ios

I am working on a project, where in the basket, just before checkout, a customer can see which seats he has selected, in which part of the room etc. Sadly, there is so much information necessary, that I can't show it on one line.

This is why I have chosen to make that specific div scrollable horizontally. One problem though: on mobiles, the div doesn't get a horizontal scroll-bar when viewed on mobiles.

I therefore need to create some kind of "call to action", so a user knows he can scroll horizontally on that specific area. What could I add design-wise, so a user knows he can interact by scrolling horizontally?

[image]

I have tried to activate a scroll bar, but it's impossible to do by code, that's why I resort to the graphic design part of SO now :)

Comment: I'd honestly redesign to remove the need for horizontal scrolling. No matter what you implement, many, many users will never realize then can scroll horizontally.

Comment: Yes, we are considering that option, but have not yet found a way to display that much information on such a small space (it's also up to the backend-devs to adapt the code). At the moment this is the best solution, which is why I am asking this.

Comment: @Rvervuurt That is not a backend issue at all, layout and the way data is presented is front end. Please see [this UX.SE question](http://ux.stackexchange.com/q/1459/38942)

Comment: I've actually fixed it with CSS and displaying (or blocking) some cells with `:nth-child(*)`. Works really well now.